# Give access to the corresponding asp page based on user id and password enter in login control

Tags: asp.net

I have two folders "Admin", and "User" folders in my ASP.NET web application project. Under the Admin folder there is a "Admin.aspx" page, and under the User folder there is a "User.aspx" page. I have another page called "Login.aspx" under the Account folder. For this login page, I have used the built-in Login control from the toolbox. Based on id and password given in the fields the corresponding webpage must be invoked. For example, when I enter the  username as "admin" and password as "password" **(basically admin user)**, it should load the Admin.aspx page. On the other hand when the username is "mike" and password is "mike123"**(basically normal users)**, the application should load User.aspx page. I have already created the required access rules for the "Admin" and "User" folders by using the "ASP.NET configuration" wizard. My issue here is mapping the corresponding aspx page based on id and password entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String[] users = Roles.GetRolesForUser(Login1.UserName);
        if (users.Contains("admin"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Admin.aspx");
        }
        else if (users.Contains("users"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Secure/User.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, I am assuming you are using the standard SqlMembership provider and forms authentication.

Using the Web Site Administration Tool to manage your logins provides the mechanism for authentication.  I suggest to configure and use User Roles to define access to web site functionality.

To redirect to a specific page depending on roles looks like:
Handle the LoggedIn event of the Login control.

```
protected void LoginControl_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

       if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Site Admin"))
       {
          Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Admin.aspx");
       }
       else if  (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("User")) 
       {
          Response.Redirect("~/User/User.aspx");
       }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Debug.WriteLine("Exception in d: " + ex.Message);
       throw;
    }
}
```

You also need to provide access to the Login.aspx page outside of the secure sections of the site via the web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="MyApplication" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="60">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

This is just one of any number of solutions you could implement. There are many resource online to help you get this going.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have already resolved this by the answer which I myself posted in this question.

Comment: I saw that after I submitted my answer...took to long for me to type! ;-)  You could simplify your code by using the User.IsInRole("xxxx") method.  Cheers.